# Azure Web Roles and Instances

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I have a web role with **multiple instances**. I'd like to send an email to my customers with their statistics every morning at 7AM. 
My problem is the following: if I use a **Cron job** to do the work mails will be sent **multiple times**.

How can I configure my instances in order to send only one email to each of my customers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my experience, I think you can try to use a unique instance id to be ensure there is a single instance works for emailing as cron job.

Here is a simple code.

```
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.RoleEnvironment;

String instanceId = RoleEnvironment.getCurrentRoleInstance().getId();
if("<instace-id-for-running-cronjob>".equals(instanceId)) {
    // Coding for cron job
    .....
}
```

As reference, please see the description of the function `RoleInstance.getId` below.

> **Returns the ID of this instance.**
>   The returned ID is unique to the application domain of the role's instance. If an instance is terminated and has been configured to restart automatically, the restarted instance will have ***the same ID*** as the terminated instance.

More details for using the class above from Azure SDK for Java, please see  the list of classes below.

- [RoleEnvironment](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/serviceruntime/RoleEnvironment.html)
- [RoleInstance](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/serviceruntime/RoleInstance.html)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the way to solve this problem with `Multi-instance Cloud Services`  would be to use `Master Election` pattern. What you would do is at 7:00 AM (or whenever your CRON job will fire), all your instances will try to acquire lease on a blob. However only one instance will be successful in acquiring the lease while other instances will fail with `PreConditionFailed (419)` error (make sure you catch this exception!). The instance that acquires the lease is essentially a `Master` and that instance will send out email.

Obviously the problem with this approach is that what if this `Master` instance fails to deliver the messages. But I guess that's another question :).